# file upload not working in meteor JS

Tags: meteor

```js
 Meteor.startup(function(){
   console.log(process.env.PWD);
   UploadServer.init({
      tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/tmp',
      uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/',
      getDirectory: function(file, formData) {
        return formData.contentType;
      },
        finished: function(file, folder, formFields){
          console.log(file.name); // ServerSession.set('image_name', file.name);
        }
    })
  });
```

this is my code which is not working any help?

Thanks

Comment: Give me error like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)"

Comment: Did you create the directory if not please run this command  mkdir -p .uploads/tmp

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to checkCreateDirectories set true. If you are not setting this true then you have to create directly menually here is the exmaple how can you do that

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  UploadServer.init({
    tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/tmp',
    uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/',
    checkCreateDirectories: true,
    getDirectory: function(fileInfo, formData) {
      // create a sub-directory in the uploadDir based on the content type (e.g. 'images')
      return formData.contentType;
    },
    finished: function(fileInfo, formFields) {
      // perform a disk operation
    },
    cacheTime: 100,
    mimeTypes: {
        "xml": "application/xml",
        "vcf": "text/x-vcard"
    }
  });
});
```

Also please have a look on file upload using collection-FS which provide alot of good things. Please check my github demo https://github.com/PankajJatav/meteor-image-upload-demo

Comment: One more question i upload images in .uploads folder at root. but i can't display this image in website. which URL i use??

Comment: For doing that you have to read the image on server side using fs module then convert it into base64 encoded image then send it to client.

Comment: I hope that make sense to you.

Comment: image already uploaded in .uploads folder i just want to display image using   image tag . in image src i need require image URL

Comment: You can't not access .upload folder on client side, you can only access public, lib and client folder on client side. So If you are sending some other file from different folder then you have read it first and then send back it to client side.

Comment: Can you please add a new issue for that, because its hard to add code on comment. If my answer work you can accept that as well.

Comment: see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929138/how-to-read-the-image-on-server-side-using-fs-module-then-convert-it-into-base64

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937010/how-to-set-session-in-template-html-file-in-meteor-js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951551/template-rendered-is-not-working-properly-in-meteor-js