# How to read the image on server side using fs module then convert it into base64 encoded image then send it to client in meteor

Tags: meteor

How to read the image on server side using fs module then convert it into base64 encoded image then send it to client in meteor js for display image at client side.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return you the base64 encoded images form the server.

```
var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require ? __meteor_bootstrap__.require : Npm.require;
var fs = require('fs');
Meteor.methods({
    /*Reruen the byte64 encoded image*/
    imgSend : function (imgName) {
        var filePath = process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/tmp' + imgName;
        var data = fs.readFileSync( filePath );
        data = new Buffer(data, 'binary').toString('base64');
        return "data:image/png;base64,"+data ;
    }
})
```

If you can save the images name list in a collection that will allow you to manage the imgname easily. Be sure that you are using unique name for images.

Comment: give me error fs is undefined i already install  meteor add cfs:standard-packages

Comment: You don't need cfs  package for that you just have to import fs package. For that I have updated my answer.

Comment: Your welcome my friend. You can accept my answers if they solve your problems.

Comment: Hello
image upload with prefix null in image name like : nullupload_certificate.png
any idea how to remove null in image name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934006/session-email-become-undefined-when-i-reload-page-in-meteor-js