# session email become undefined when i reload page in meteor JS

Tags: meteor

i store email using session .set('email','email name') but when i reload page that time this session email is become undefined. i use Session.get('email') to get user email.

```js
Router.route('profile', {
  path: '/profile',
  data: function() {
     $("body").removeClass('home');
     this.render('profile');
      setTimeout(function(){ 

        $('#username').html(Session.get('first_name'));
        $('#profile_username').html(Session.get('first_name'));
        $('#setting_name').val(Session.get('first_name'));
        $('#setting_username').val(Session.get('first_name'));
        $('#setting_email').val(Session.get('email'));
        $('#user_id').val(Session.get('id'));

        $('.setting_day').val(Session.get('day'));
        $('.setting_month').val(Session.get('month'));
        $('.setting_year').val(Session.get('year'));

        if(Session.get('image')!= ''){
          $('.user_profile_image').attr("src",Session.get('image'));
        }
        
        if(Session.get('gender') == 0){
            $('#user_gender').html('Male');
        }else{
            $('#user_gender').html('Female');
        }
            $('#day').html(Session.get('day'));
            $('#month').html(Session.get('month'));
            $('#year').html(Session.get('year'));
      },100);
  },
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    
    alert(Session.get('email'));
    if(Session.get('email')){
        this.next();
    }else {
       
        this.redirect('/');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

install persistent package Session. Your session variables will persist across routes also. You need to configure it via Meteor settings. so don't forget include the settings when you run project.

[u2622:persistent-session](https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session)

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page page in meteor all the client side reactive things reinitialize So if you want to keep the email when page refresh then you have to send it on the server and then you can fetch this when according to your  need. You can save it into a collection and then fetch from a meteor call or publish-subscribe according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page you are no longer in the same session so what you describe is the expected and correct default behavior. There is a package (I don't know it's name right now, but should be easy to find on atmospherejs) which gives you Session.setPersistent(...). I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Session.setPersistent(...) also not save session data after page load