# Put the email address from Meteor.loginWithGoogle into a Session variable

Tags: meteor

I'm using `Meteor.loginWithGoogle` in my app. I'm trying to get the email address of the google user to put it into a `Session` variable.

```
Template.login.events({
  'click #google-login': function(event){
    Meteor.loginWithGoogle({}, function(err){
      if ( err ) {
        throw new Meteor.Error("Google login failed");
      } else {
        const emailAddress = ?; // how do I get this from google?
        Session.set('email',emailAddress);
        Router.go('/profile');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether i understood your question, but i guess what you're trying to ask is: "After a user performed a loginWithGoogle, how can i get his email address, and set it into his Session?"

After a login, `Meteor.user()` holds the current user document. Having that in mind:

```
const currentUser = Meteor.user();
const userGoogleServiceMain = currentUser.services.google.email;
```

With that, you can have:

```
Template.login.events({
  'click #google-login': function(event){
    Meteor.loginWithGoogle({}, function(err){
      if ( err ) {
        throw new Meteor.Error("Google login failed");
      } else {
        const currentUser = Meteor.user();
        const emailAddress = currentUser.services.google.email;
        Session.set('email',emailAddress);
        Router.go('/profile');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

You may find more details about that in: [Meteor documentation](http://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#oauth-calling-api) and http://cs.wellesley.edu/~mashups/pages/meteor6.html

Comment: Glad to help. If its the correct answer, you might want to mark it