# template rendered is not working properly in meteor JS

Tags: meteor

template rendered is not working

when user successfully login in to system i redirect to profile page that time data is not get but if i visit another page and come back to profile page that time it is working fine. also when i reload page that time also it is not working

here is code

```js
Template.profile.rendered = function(){
    
    var user_email  = {};
    user_email.mail = Session.get('email');
    
    var imgName  = Session.get('image');
    Meteor.call("imgSend",imgName,function(error, result){
        $('.user_profile_image').attr("src",result)
    });
    
    Meteor.call("getLinkMeta",user_email,function(error, result){
        
        var link_all_info = [];       
        var walldata      = [];
        var total         = result.length;
        var processed     = 0;
        
        var t =  result.forEach(function (entry){
   
              var link_info     = {};
              link_info.link_id = entry._id;                 

              Meteor.call("getCommentList",link_info, function (error, res){
      
                if(error){
                    console.log("e");
                }else{
                    entry.comments = res;            
                }
                processed++
                if(processed == total){                                   
                   //walldata=result;
                }
             });                           
        });
        Template.profile.walldata = function(){  
                 return result;
        };    
   //return result;
  });
}
```

```js
Router.route('profile', {
  path: '/profile',
  data: function() {
    
    /* Meteor.subscribe("Users");
       Meteor.subscribe("Link");
       Meteor.subscribe("Linkfav");
       Meteor.subscribe("LinkLike");
       Meteor.subscribe("LinkComment"); */ 
    
     $("body").removeClass('home');
     this.render('profile');
    
      setTimeout(function(){ 

        $('#username').html(Session.get('first_name'));
        $('#profile_username').html(Session.get('first_name'));
        $('#setting_name').val(Session.get('first_name'));
        $('#setting_username').val(Session.get('first_name'));
        $('#setting_email').val(Session.get('email'));
        $('#user_id').val(Session.get('id'));

        $('.setting_day').val(Session.get('day'));
        $('.setting_month').val(Session.get('month'));
        $('.setting_year').val(Session.get('year'));

        if(Session.get('image')!= ''){
          $('.user_profile_image').attr("src",Session.get('image'));
        }
        
        if(Session.get('gender') == 0){
            $('#user_gender').html('Male');
        }else{
            $('#user_gender').html('Female');
        }
            $('#day').html(Session.get('day'));
            $('#month').html(Session.get('month'));
            $('#year').html(Session.get('year'));
      },100);
    
  },onBeforeAction:function(){
    
    if(Session.get('email')){
        this.next();
    }else {
        //this.next();
        this.redirect('/');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Two meteor calls and then a loop of meteor calls inside the second one? This is going to be really slow, asynchronous, and problematic. What are you trying to do? It looks like you are trying to build the data context for your template but in a very non-meteoric way.

Comment: @MichelFloyd is right.  If you need to upload some data from server that is stored inside Mongo.Collection (like comments, in your case), you should use publish/subscribe API. Usually you will subscribe in Template.profile.onCreated or in waitOn callback in case you are using iron:router package. Check out MDG's todo list as example: https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh/reload the page Session values are get undefined. You can get the current user email using meteor.user(). You just have to  replace you session.get('email') like this.

```
var user_email  = {};
user_email.mail = Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
```

I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: page is not refreshing i just use "Router.route('/circles')" for redirect login page to profile page.  when page is reload my session mail value is not undefined because i use Session.setPersistent. my issue is page is not rendered properly after login.

Comment: Use "Router.go('/circles')" instead of "Router.route('/circles')".

Comment: see code which i updated and let me know what is issue.
Thanks

Comment: I didn't see that you are setting your session values anywhere. And please don't use too much session that is a bad code for meteor.

Comment: Session.setPersistent('first_name', result.first_name);